# Interfacing std::filesystem::path with libraries that expect UTF-8 char*?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm looking to use `std::filesystem::path` to easily manipulate paths, but the libraries I'm using expect a `const char*` in UTF-8 encoding on all platforms.

I see that [I can get a `u8string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string), but its `c_str()` returns a `char8_t*`.

Is there some way for me to go from `filesystem::path` to a UTF-8 encoded `char*` on all platforms?

Comment: Doesn't `char8_t*` implies that it is `char*` encoded as utf8? Just different type for compile time differentiating from a regular ASCII string? The `u8string` is a C++20 thing - it returned a `string` till then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A buffer of `char8_t` can be reasonably safely cast to a `char const*` pointer and passed to the other API.

`char8_t` is a distinct type whose underlying storage is identical to an `unsigned char`.  Casting `unsigned char` bits to `char` is legal.

`char` may be signed or unsigned, so fiddling with it is somewhat dangerous in portable code.  But simply passing it through (read only) to another API is very safe.

Usually aliasing one type as another is illegal in C++, but `char` is one of the types with special dispensation to alias.

Note it is not legal to cast a buffer of `char` directly into a pointer to `char8_t`.  So if it is providing utf-8 sequences in `char` data and you need it as a `char8_t` buffer, you'll have to copy it over to a `char8_t` buffer (which can be done via memcpy or similar) to stay within standard-defined behavior.

Comment: In C++20, one probably should use `bit_cast`.

Answer (score 3):

The very reason why `char8_t` is different from `char` is to make sure it's users are aware that this is not a simple char, and separate encoding/decoding is required to process it. Other than that, it is the same as `char`.

It looks like the libraries you are using fail to recognize this or are pre-c++20 libraries. In either case, you can use `reinterpet_cast` to cast `const char8_t*` to `const char*` - this would be one of the rare examples when such cast would be appropriate.